# Use mysql_fetch_array() with foreach() instead of while()

Tags: php

i want to know how do we convert the following code to work with foreach

```
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8;"; 

    $result_select = mysql_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)) {
        $ename = stripslashes($row['name']);
        $eemail = stripcslashes($row['email']);
        $epost = stripslashes($row['post']);
        $eid = $row['id'];

        $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=".md5(strtolower($eemail))."&size=70";

        echo ('<img src = "' . $grav_url . '" alt="Gravatar">'.'<br/>');

        echo $eid . '<br/>';

        echo $ename . '<br/>';

        echo $eemail . '<br/>';

        echo $epost . '<br/><br/><br/><br/>';
```

Comment: Why? I don't see any reason to change your code. Using a foreach will only make it longer and use more memory.

Comment: Well, don't go learning stuff that will make your code worse. Instead, learn this: don't use a foreach loop with mysql_fetch_array().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can code like this:

```
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8;";
$result_select = mysql_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
    $rows[] = $row;
foreach($rows as $row){ 
    $ename = stripslashes($row['name']);
    $eemail = stripcslashes($row['email']);
    $epost = stripslashes($row['post']);
    $eid = $row['id'];

    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=".md5(strtolower($eemail))."&size=70";

    echo ('<img src = "' . $grav_url . '" alt="Gravatar">'.'<br/>');

    echo $eid . '<br/>';

    echo $ename . '<br/>';

    echo $eemail . '<br/>';

    echo $epost . '<br/><br/><br/><br/>';
}
```

As you can see, **it's still need a loop while to get data from mysql_fetch_array**

Comment: cant it be done without using the while loop? i mean is it not possible at at all to fetch the data from the database and iterate it using foreach loop without actually using while loop...

Comment: You can't. **Foreach** is a loop using for an exist array, to loop through each its item. To fetch data, a **while loop** (or **for loop**) is required. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: No, the mysql functions retrieve 1 row at a time, not an array of rows. If you switch to PDO (http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) fetchAll() can be used to get the resultset as an array.

Comment: i quite liked the simplicity of how you explained things, it is quite simple to understand, thanks a lot for making me understand the possibility of foreach loop.. that was really very helpful..:)

Answer (score 6):

There's not a good way to convert it to foreach, because `mysql_fetch_array()` just fetches the next result from `$result_select`.  If you *really* wanted to foreach, you could do pull all the results into an array first, doing something like the following:

```
$result_list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)) {
   result_list[] = $row;
}

foreach($result_list as $row) {
   ...
}
```

But there's no good reason I can see to do that - and you still have to use the while loop, which is unavoidable due to how `mysql_fetch_array()` works.  Why is it so important to use a foreach()?

**EDIT:** If this is just for learning purposes: you can't convert this to a `foreach`.  You have to have a pre-existing array to use a `foreach()` instead of a `while()`, and `mysql_fetch_array()` fetches one result per call - there's no pre-existing array for `foreach()` to iterate through.

Comment: i am learning php, and i want to learn the possibility, actually i was unable to find any good tuts on internet that could explain me the process of using the foreach() for database manipulation, i would appreciate if someone could point me the correct way (tut), and the possibility of using foreach loop with database query.

Comment: The right way is: do NOT use foreach loop with database queries.

Comment: You can't find tutorials because you simply can't use a foreach() for database manipulation using the standard PHP MySQL libraries (and you don't want to use anything else).  If for some reason you really want to use a foreach() and have all your rows in an array at once, you have to do it as above.

Comment: To reiterate: there is no possibility of using the foreach loop with a database query.  It just doesn't work that way.  You can only pull out one result at a time.

Comment: i got it, thank you for the quicker response, and for a great help..cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

To use `foreach` would require you have an array that contains every row from the query result. Some DB libraries for PHP provide a `fetch_all` function that provides an appropriate array but I could not find one for `mysql` (however the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) extension does) . You could of course write your own, like so

```
function mysql_fetch_all($result) {
   $rows = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $rows[] = $row;
   }
   return $rows;
}
```

However I must echo the "why?" Using this function you are creating two loops instead of one, and requring the entire result set be loaded in to memory. For sufficiently large result sets, this could become a serious performance drag. And for what?

```
foreach (mysql_fetch_all($result) as $row)
```

vs

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

`while` is just as concise and IMO more readable.

**EDIT** There is another option, but it is pretty absurd. You could use the [Iterator Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)

```
class MysqlResult implements Iterator {
  private $rownum = 0;
  private $numrows = 0;
  private $result;

  public function __construct($result) {
    $this->result = $result;
    $this->numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  }

  public function rewind() {
    $this->rownum = 0;
  }

  public function current() {
    mysql_data_seek($this->result, $this->rownum);
    return mysql_fetch_array($this->result);
  }

  public function key() {
    return $this->rownum;
  }

  public function next() {
    $this->rownum++;
  }

  public function valid() {
    return $this->rownum < $this->numrows ? true : false;
  }
}

$rows = new MysqlResult(mysql_query($query_select));

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  //code...
}
```

In this case, the `MysqlResult` instance fetches rows only on request just like with `while`, but wraps it in a nice foreach-able package. While you've saved yourself a loop, you've added the overhead of class instantiation and a boat load of function calls, not to mention a good deal of added code complexity.

But you asked if it could be done without using `while` (or `for` I imagine). Well it *can* be done, just like that. Whether it *should* be done is up to you.

Comment: i am not used to oop, but thanks for that lengthy code BTW, i went through it and must admit i learned something from it. thank you for your extended help :)

Answer (score 0):

the most obvious way to make `foreach` a possibility includes materializing the whole resultset in an array, which will probably kill you memory-wise, sooner or later.  you'd need to turn to iterators to avoid that problem.  see http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it like this

```
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8;"; 

$result_select = mysql_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error());

 foreach($result_select as $row){
    $ename = stripslashes($row['name']);
    $eemail = stripcslashes($row['email']);
    $epost = stripslashes($row['post']);
    $eid = $row['id'];

    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=".md5(strtolower($eemail))."&size=70";

    echo ('<img src = "' . $grav_url . '" alt="Gravatar">'.'<br/>');

    echo $eid . '<br/>';

    echo $ename . '<br/>';

    echo $eemail . '<br/>';

    echo $epost . '<br/><br/><br/><br/>';
 }
```