# Fetch array function doubling values in each position of array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I am getting strange behaviour from this function.

**Input**

```
    public function fetch_array($result_set) 
{
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) 
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
            print_r($row);
            break;
        }
        return $rows;

}
```

I have made the function run once but it its duplicating a row from my MySQL query result.

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Sarah [first_name] => Sarah [1] => Palin [second_name] => Palin )
```

It should be

**Correct Output**

```
Array ( [first_name] => Sarah [second_name] => Palin )
```

I used this SO question example

[Use mysql_fetch_array() with foreach() instead of while()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442895/use-mysql-fetch-array-with-foreach-instead-of-while)

**Not my query or Mysql result fault**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/icUYI.png

[image]

---

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The `$rows` array is exactly the same as the `$row` array returned from `mysql_fetch_array`. So why not just return `$row` after you fetched it? On a side note: **don't** use the `mysql_` functions. They will soon be removed from PHP. And use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: technically it isn't the same, it is an array containing the $row array, but your point is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an error, it's the intended behavior of `mysql_fetch_array()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You can either set the `result_type` flag, or you can just use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Sure, just replace `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)` with `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)`

Answer (score 2):

When using mysql_fetch_array, feed it the MYSQL_ASSOC flag.

EDIT: Here's your code, with the appropriate change

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Also, you can get them with just the numeric indices by feeding it MYSQL_NUM

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get one result and wanting the other is because you are pushing an array($row) inside a new array ($rows). By pushing something in an array(The brackets you use) you get an auto incrementing key with it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$rows['name'] = $row['name'];
$rows['second_name] = $row['second_name'];
```

...

instead of

```
$rows[] = $row;
```

Comment: Thanks, however if I am wanting to use this function with other data I dont think this would work

Answer (score 1):

By default `mysql_fetch_array` has two keys for each database column -- one with the numerical key and one with the associative key.
You can do this to tell it only to fetch the numeric keys:

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

It is completely normal and expected behaviour. If you just want the associative array, use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```