# php MySQL fetch printing double?

Tags: php

When I make a sql query and echo it out it repeats the first row twice

```
$sql = 'SELECT one,two,three FROM justAnExampleForSO where one = one';
$info = mysql_query(sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($info )>0){


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($info )) {

            foreach($row as $key => $var)
            {
                if($key == 'one')
                    echo $var.",";                    
                else if($key == 'two')
                    echo $var.",";
                else if($key == 'three')
                    echo $var.";";
            }           

        }

    }
```

so for example say I am attempting to get cols one, two, three
When the output is echoed it would echo

```
one, one, two,three;
```

I am not sure if this is a duplicate of this question or not because I couldn't full understand his problem. [Fetch array function doubling values in each position of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921939/fetch-array-function-doubling-values-in-each-position-of-array)

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed. use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or atleast use [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (writing the `i` after `mysql` will be majority cases. don't be lazy. write the `i`.) .... and show the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Because `mysql_fetch_array` returns both numerically indexed values and string indexes, and due to the fun of type casting rules `"one"` equals `0`. Use `===` instead of `==` to prevent that, or use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to forgo the numerical indexes you're not using anyway.

You should also be doing it much more simply than a `foreach..if..else`:

```
echo $row['one'], ', ', $row['two'], ', ', $row['three'], ';';
```

Comment: geez.... i forgot everything about `mysql_fetch_array`. should have wrote this answer.... blessing in disguise i suppose.