# foreach on resultset mysql return only one value randomic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, resultset

I am trying do some simple select in one script.

I see if I try to read my resultset with a while there isn't any problem but if I try to use foreach, I just read 1 o 2 value all wrong...
why?

```
$sql = " select * from tutorials_tbl";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
 }


 $sql = " select * from tutorials_tbl";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
    foreach($rows= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH) as $row) {
     printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
    }
```

-

```
* OUTPUT WHILE*

ID: 0 Name: title0
ID: 1 Name: title1
```

ecc....

```
*OUTPUT FOREACH*

 ID: 1 Name: 
 ID: 1 Name: 
 ID: t Name: i
 ID: t Name: i
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and use mysqli_* or PDO for this purpose. and also write print_r($row) in both while;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one row with foreach is that the function mysql_fetch_array() only returns a single record.

In the while loop the condition where the function is called is re-evaluated on every loop.  This is perfect.

The foreach you have is quite strange and I'm thinking what happens is that mysql_fetch_array() reads one record as an array into the variable $rows,  and then it would iterate over each COLUMN in the record....   in other words $rows is just one row, and $row is one value in the row.
The reason you only see one or two letters in the output is because $row[0] on a string just gives you the 0th letter in the string.

The only way the foreach would work is with a 'fetch all' function which gives an array of arrays.  But you'd have to create that yourself... it would probably mainly contain the while loop :)

If you use PDO as suggested it comes with fetchAll capabilities.

Comment: is that the problem..... i try to do what i do with some framework php and i think they  build the fetchAll for you...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = " select * from tutorials_tbl";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row['Attribute-1'], $row['Attribute-2']);  
}

foreach($rows= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH) as $row)
{
  echo $row['Attribute-1'];
  echo $row['Attribute-2'];
}
```

This question has already been asked :     [Use mysql_fetch_array() with foreach() instead of while()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442895/use-mysql-fetch-array-with-foreach-instead-of-while)
if you want you can refer from here as well. :D

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
 $sql = " select * from tutorials_tbl";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $rows= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

 foreach($rows as $row){
  echo 'ID '. $row->id.' Name '.$row->name;

 }
```