# how to retrieve data from mysql db with loops other than while loop in php?

Tags: php, sql, loops

I am working with mysqli in php but i'd like to know how can i retrieve data from DB with loops other than while loop?

I always use while loop to retrieve data and I've never seen anybody to use another loop to do it. is this the only way to retrieve data!!?

```
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM article";
if($get_from_db = $db_connection->query($select_query)){
    if($get_from_db->num_rows > 0){
        while($result = $get_from_db->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo "id: " . $result['id'] . '<br>'; 
            echo "title: " . $result['title'] . '<br>'; 
            echo "context: " . $result['context'] . '<br>'; 
            echo "=========================================<br>";
        }
    }
    $get_from_db->free();
}else{
    //do somthing...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use mysql\_fetch\_array() with foreach() instead of while()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442895/use-mysql-fetch-array-with-foreach-instead-of-while)

Comment: It's not the only way but it's the simplest. Is there a problem or are you just curious?

Comment: i'm just curious!

Answer (score 3):

The while loop is not used to retrieve the data, it is used to fetch it from the mysqli instance that holds the query result, and to use another loop you would need to know before hand the number of rows returned from the query result.

What I think you can do is use `fetch_all` to fetch all the elements at once, and then you can use for example a foreach loop:

```
$rows = $get_from_db->fetch_all();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "id: " . $row['id'] . '<br>'; 
    echo "title: " . $row['title'] . '<br>'; 
    echo "context: " . $row['context'] . '<br>'; 
    echo "=========================================<br>";
}
```

Edit: You can also use for (with the same behaviour of while):

```
for (;$result = $get_from_db->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in the form of array, you can use `foreach` loop

```
foreach($results as $result){
    echo "id: " . $result['id'] . '<br>'; 
    echo "title: " . $result['title'] . '<br>'; 
    echo "context: " . $result['context'] . '<br>'; 
    echo "=========================================<br>";
 }
```